# Android ListView Navigation With Up and Down Button

Tags: android

I have made a custom `ListView` like the following

[image: Listview]

Currently I am showing only 2 views and  updating the `ListView` adapter when user clicks on the navigation button and calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.Is it possible to make default implementation on the navigation so that we get the default behavior of `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify your question? When you press the up/down buttons, is the data fetched from an external source or you already have it saved. And what behaviour are you trying to achieve? ListView should take care of all scrolling.If your intention is to mimic the scrolling of listViews using arrow keys, you can dispatch appropriate key down event on the ListView from your buttons.

Nb: If your goal is to make a custom ListView, like the one showed in your image, you need to extend the Adapter class and do your customization there.

Comment: I have using custom `ListView` and I have data which is already saved, and again using `Adapter` ..